# Does Quantum Heisenberg Spin Model obey Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein statistics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, identical-particles

Does Quantum Heisenberg Spin Model obey Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein statistics?

We want to study a $N$-Spin Quantum Heisenberg Spin chain:

Hamiltonian is:

$$\displaystyle {\hat  H}=-J\sum _{{j=1}}^{{N}}\sigma _{j}\sigma _{{j+1}}-h\sum _{{j=1}}^{{N}}\sigma _{j} \quad .$$

From above Hamiltonian, we can calculate its partition function.

Question: When the number of spins is very large, approach to infinity, will this system obey Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein statistics ?

Comment: Can you clarify what it means for a *model* to obey Fermi-Dirac statistics?

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: You can symmetresize the system with either statistics

Answer (score 1):

In the Heisenberg model, spins are neither fermions, nor bosons. Indeed, the Hamiltonian of a gas of free fermions is of the form
$$H=\sum_k \varepsilon_k c_k^+c_k$$
with the anti-commutation relations
$$\{c_k,c_q\}= \{c_k^+,c_q^+\}=0,\quad
\quad \{c_k,c_q^+\}=\delta_{k,q}$$
The system obeys the Fermi-Dirac statistics, i.e. the grand-canonical partition function is
$$\Xi={\rm Tr\ } e^{-\beta(H-N\mu)}
   =\prod_k \sum_{n_k=0,1} e^{-\beta(\varepsilon_k-\mu)n_k}$$
It follows that the probability to find a fermion in the energy level $\varepsilon_k$ is
$$\langle n_k\rangle={1\over e^{\beta(\varepsilon_k-\mu)}+1}$$
For bosons, anti-commutation relations are replaced by commutation relations and the system obeys Bose-Einstein statistics.

The quantum Heisenberg model is expressed in terms of spin operators, Pauli matrices in the case of spin 1/2. The latter do not satisfy the above-mentioned anti-commutation, nor commutation relations. The system does not obey Fermi-Dirac, nor Bose-Einstein, statistics. The canonical partition function is computed as usual as
$${\cal Z}={\rm Tr\ } e^{-\beta H}$$

The confusion may come from the fact that the Ising model, another spin model with spins 1/2, can be solved using a mapping onto a gas of free fermions. In this case, the fermions obey the Fermi-Dirac statistics but this property is not transferred to the spins.

Comment: You said: :"The system does not obey Fermi-Dirac, nor Bose-Einstein, statistics.", so does it obey Boltzmann statistics ? (I got the impression that any physical system must obey one of those statistics, is this impression wrong ? )

Comment: Fermi-Dirac statistics applies only to non-interacting fermions and Bose-Einstein statistics to non-interacting bosons. In any other case, one should compute the canonical partition function with the general formula $Z={\rm Tr\ }e^{-\beta H}$.